# Allen Bradley Connected Components RS Linx USB Connection

Tags: usb, microcontroller, plc

I am working with Allen Bradley's Connected Component Workbench to program a Micro 830 Controller. I'm having an issue when I try to connect to the controller via USB. The USB never comes up in RSLinx even though Windows Device Manager says the driver is installed and working correctly. I am running Connected Components Workbench version 10.01.00 on a Windows 10 machine plugged directly into the Controller via USB and I know that I can connect to the PLC with another machine in the office. Is there still something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Thing to try:

1) Most of Allen Bradley's equipment only work on a USB 2.0 or below. My computer has both 2.0 and 3.0 ports. Only 2.0 ports will talk to a 830 PLC.

2) Flow this guide: 
https://theautomationblog.com/setup-micro800-usb-comms/

3) Download and install the newest version of RsLinx    https://compatibility.rockwellautomation.com/Pages/MultiProductFindDownloads.aspx?crumb=112&refSoft=1&toggleState=&versions=51543

4) Call you local AB sales office and ask for help. If you stop by they will help you for free. All sales office have support people that help.